# How do you host a gatsby site under a subpath

Tags: gatsby

Im trying to deploy a gatsby site which has urls like

1. /biz
2. /biz-f

But now I want to host this site under a subpath in my domain like

1. www.example.com/lp/biz   -> /biz
2. www.example.com/lp/biz-f -> /biz-f

I am using a reverse proxy to serve the gatsby site whenever it sees `/lp/*`

The problem is gatsby loads resources like `/app.js` and then some json files like `static/d/375/***.json`
This causes problems as now the browser is looking for something like `www.example.com/app.js` instead of `www.example.com/lp/app.js`

I was able to fix the js and css by doing [what was mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8833#issuecomment-458147983). Basically I prefixed the css and js filenames with something like `gatsby-asset-***`. And added this to the proxy. But I cant fix the json files and also the service worker js file. Im not sure how to prefix those file names.

Is there like a proper way of doing this?

Comment: That link is broken or sits behind a private repo

Comment: @ksav fixed the link

Comment: Have you read this : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/ ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand but thats about the links in the app. This is about the assets.

Comment: I just tried again and path-prefix works for everything and not only for the link.